# Push an element anywhere in an object with Lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am using lodash to manipulate a JSON object. I am not against using Vanilla JS but since I am working on a PoC for now, I am just looking for the fastest solution to test.

So here is the problem I am facing: I want to be able to easily `push` an element to an array anywhere in an object, and it should create automatically all the missing nodes, including the last array.

For example, let's say I have an empty object, and I would like to create a function that can populate my object with the right values, for example:

```
let dl = {};

customPush(dl, 'a.b', { c: 3, d: 4 });
// or
customPush(dl, ['a', 'b'], { c: 3, d: 4 });
```

Should create:

```
dl = {
  a: {
    b: [{
      c: 3,
      d: 4
    }]
  }
}
```

This is everything I tried but none of them are working:

```
function customPush(obj, path, item) {
  // This is just assigning the item to the path, not pushing to a new array
  _.set(dl, path, item);

  // This one is not doing anything visible
  _.get(dl, path, []).push(item);

  // Pushing in this one doesn't work with a path like 'a.b'
  if (_.has(dl, path)) {
    dl.path.push(item);
  } else {
    _.set(dl, path, [item]);
  }

  // Any idea?
  ...
}
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: People have requested this kind of function in Lodash [here](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/1145) and [here](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/1315). Hasn't been added yet, but hopefully will at some point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your attempt here is *very* close:

```
// Pushing in this one doesn't work with a path like 'a.b'
if (_.has(dl, path)) {
  dl.path.push(item);
} else {
  _.set(dl, path, [item]);
}
```

You simply need to use `_.get` if the array is there and `_.set` if it isn't. You are already doing the latter part.

```js
function customPush(obj, path, item) {
  if (_.has(obj, path)) {
    let arr = _.get(obj, path);
    arr.push(item)
  } else {
    _.set(obj, path, [item]);
  }
}

let objOne = { }
let objTwo = { a: [] }

let objThree = { 
  a: {
    b: {
      c: {
      }
    }
  }
}

let objFour = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: {
        d: []
      }
    }
  }
}

customPush(objOne, "a", "item");
console.log("objOne", objOne);

customPush(objTwo, "a", "item");
console.log("objTwo", objTwo);

customPush(objThree, "a.b.c.d", "item");
console.log("objThree", objThree);

customPush(objFour, "a.b.c.d", "item");
console.log("objFour", objFour);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Worth noting that this only works if the key either *doesn't exist* or it *it's value is an array*. If you give the path to an existing key with a non-array value you'd get an error. You can check that using [`_.isArray`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#isArray) but I am not sure what you want to do if a key exists and does not hold an array.